# GCP memory deploy symfony

Tags: composer-php, out-of-memory, gcloud

I am new on GCP and I'm trying to deploy my Symfony 4 application but I have a memory message error on composer install.
I'm using App Engine Flex.

```
Step #1: Package operations: 115 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
Step #1:   - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.4.0): Loading from cache
Step #1: The following exception is caused by a lack of memory or swap, or not having swap configured
Step #1: Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details
Step #1: 
Step #1: PHP Warning:  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 952
Step #1: 
Step #1: Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 952
Step #1:                                                      
Step #1:   [ErrorException]                                   
Step #1:   proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory  
Step #1:                                                      
Step #1: 
Step #1: install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
Step #1: 
Step #1: error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
Finished Step #1
```

Here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: php
env: flex

resources:
  memory_gb: 4

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

env_variables:
  APP_ENV: prod
  APP_SECRET: secret
  # APP_DEBUG: true

  ## For connecting to Cloud SQL with Doctrine
  ## This is used in part two of the README:
  # DATABASE_URL: mysql://root:DB_PASSWORD@localhost?unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME;dbname=symfonydb

handlers:
  # Declare the build and bundles directory as static assets to be served by the
  # App Engine CDN.
  - url: /build
    static_dir: public/build
  - url: /bundles
    static_dir: public/bundles
  - url: /js
    static_dir: public/js

  # Declare any media files in the public directory as static assets as well.
  - url: /(.*\.(ico|txt|gif|png|jpg))$
    static_files: public/\1
    upload: public/.*\.(ico|txt|gif|png|jpg)$
```

I tried to set memory_gb parameter but it has no effect.
How can I increase the memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my problem.
It was to include my composer.lock (yes I have ignored it in my .gloudignore file).

But if the problem persist, think about COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT environnement variable, maybe could help.

And, if it still does not work, maybe a Compute Engine instead of an App Engine or do your own Dockerfile for deployment.